# Print the names stored in Hashtable, at each index, in alphabetic order, without using predefined C++ functions

Tags: c++, hashtable

PROBLEM:

I have a Hashtable in which I store some names. My problem is to print the content at each index in alphabetic order.

NOTE:

I'm working in C++, and it's required not to use any predefined C++ functions. (I defined the Hashtable using a struct, then declared all the usual functions for Hashtable).

MY IDEA:

I thought of using an array, such that I could copy all the records, stored in the linked list at index "i" of Hashtable, in it (array), then sort the array and, finally, print it's content. So, in such a way for all indexes, where the head of respective linked list in not null pointer.

I think this idea is to primitive. Can you, please, give me any suggestion on this topic ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data structure is an associative container but it's not sorted (eg `std::map` vs `std::unordered_map`) then you have no way to keep them ordered while managing the structure only.

Many hash table implementation are not even able to provide random access operators, since it makes no sense for such data structure: although indices are internally required to address buckets for values they are not meaningful from a client point of view.

Your primitive idea seems reasonable, copy the keys into a **vector** / **linked list** / **array** and then sort the array.